# Flask-Migrate hangs on table modificiation

Tags: python, postgresql, flask-migrate

I have an issue on running the upgrade command with Flask-Migrate.  Originally I was trying to modify three tables at once and it hung, I narrowed it down to a specific table (the other upgrades worked without issue).  I don't see any locks on the database.  I'm using Postgres and just working in a development environment at the moment.  The migrate command seems to work fine and generates the `upgrade` method without any issues (see code)

```
def upgrade():
    # ### commands auto generated by Alembic - please adjust! ###
    op.drop_column('equipment', 'criteria_notes')
    # ### end Alembic commands ###
```

Once I run the upgrade command I get stuck here:

```
>flask db upgrade
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Context impl PostgresqlImpl.
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Will assume transactional DDL.
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Running upgrade 76bf72d8e0e4 -> 1723c01f0606, empty message
```

with a blinking cursor.  When I exit out of the command window (I'm using windows) no changes have been applied.

I've tried

- Restarting computer
- Looking for locks or other sessions with pgAdmin
- Modifying other tables, was able to add and drop columns

Comment: How big is the table in which this column exists?

Comment: @Miguel It's tiny at the moment.  11 columns 4 rows.

Comment: What happens if you try to delete the column via SQL (i.e. `ALTER TABLE ...`)? Does that hang too?

Comment: @Miguel That works. I tried that yesterday afternoon as a workaround.  I found all the SQL commands using `Flask db upgrade --sql` and updated my table and the alembic table.

Comment: Since this is still new, @Miguel I am still running into the same issue. My error originated from changing 

`icon        = db.Column(db.String(12))`

to

`icon        = db.Column(db.String)`

in one my small tables (4 columns).

Upgrading is stuck, deleting the built (but not committed) migrations and redoing does not help, downgrading 1 migration version lower is stuck

Here is an image of pgAdmin, saying that I have to sessions open and 1 is waiting for the other to release its lock: http://imgur.com/RCJykPa

Comment: I'm also having this issue. Oddly it's only happening in my staging environment. It seems to work when i create a dump of the database and run it in my local development environment.

Comment: same issue using postgres.  If i run the commends in postgres it also hangs

Answer (score 7):

You likely have other processes connected to this DB.

This happened to me, I had celery, uwsgi, and a separate custom process all connected to the flask DB on a production server, and I was wonder why the upgrades were hanging.

Once I shut these processes down manually the upgrade script ran fine without hanging.

In my case I also tried rebooting before realizing this, and this did not help because these other processes were programmed to startup on boot.

Comment: It's possible I looked and didn't find any locks at the time.  Since I posted this I worked around it by doing the raw SQL and I also dropped that whole database at some point and re-created it in the dev environment and never had the issue return.

Comment: I had to shutdown my Flask server and then also disconnect and reconnect to my server to get it to work

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, this one happened to me because of locks,verify it using

```
select * from pg_locks;
```

There were many PIDs corresponding to each lock,I restarted the postgresql service then ran the upgrade command it worked

```
sudo systemctl restart postgresql
flask db upgrade
```

Answer (score 2):

I had this same issue with MySql due to locks and this command did the trick for me.

```
sudo service mysql restart
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was due to locks on the table.

```
select * from pg_locks;
```

in postgres showed me what was happening.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue with heroku postgres. When the db is modified locally, the application starts to act wierd. What I do is I restart the dynos for the application

In cases where the application and the db are in different containers, restart the application.